# Define multiple commands to a keybinding in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio

I want to assign a keybinding in VS Code so that when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, it stages and commits all changes in git.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: why cant you commit it yourself? what about the valid comments needed for the commit? i highly advise you to do comments manually they are such a huge part of source control history and can save you a hell of lot of time! If commits just say "Update" what use is that..

Comment: i want to automate the procces, simply a keybinding that do two commands, git stage all changes and git commit all, without args, the last command will ask me to input a message.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems like somehow just putting the commit command on a keybinding, it stages automatically, so this is solved